# Rails request format JS not working when changing innerHTML

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails

In Ruby on Rails 6, I am using a simple link tag like this

```
<a href="/users/index" data-remote="true" onclick="event.currentTarget.innerHTML = 'changed'">   Test  </a>
```

When clicking the link, everything works as expected, the "Test" text is changed to "changed" and the request is processed as JS. Now, if inside the link tag we add something like this (something with an HTML tag)

```
<a href="/users/index" data-remote="true" onclick="event.currentTarget.innerHTML = 'changed'">   <i>Test</i>  </a>
```

Rails process this link as HTML format instead of JS format. Any ideas will be appreciated! It's interesting though, if changing the innerHTML using the browser debugging console, the format is correctly handled as JS.